# Unable to install XPI in firefox

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, xpi

I have created a XPCOM add-on for firefox by the name "Sample Mozilla AddOn" from XPCOM C++ SDK. I have created an XPI file (which is an add-on installer in Firefox).

When i try to install this XPI to install my XPCOM component, i get an error "Sample Mozilla AddOn could not be installed because it has a high risk of causing stability or security problems"

I tried looking out on internet and MDN, but could not found any concrete information.

Kindly Help

Thanks and Regards
Uday Gupta

Comment: It is often due to the code/methods that has been used. Once such example is `innerHTML`. have you used it? FF object to its use and there are reasons for it.

Comment: I am not accessing/using DOM methods. The dll contains a Class that has 2 methods, one returning string and the other one returning long value. nothing complex

Comment: Then someone has to check the code. I am not familiar with SDK at all.

Comment: Where is the source code?

Comment: I thought of another thing. Pack 1 file only in a xpi and [Validate Add-on](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/addon/validate). Do it for each file in your addon and see which ones the validator complains about. That would help narrow it down.

Answer (score 0):

open mozilla firefox,
then drag the .xpi file and drop it in mozilla firefox window.
Then click install > restart firefox.
Just try it...!